# AS3 Mobile App Data/Upload/Push

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3

I am about to begin developing an app which I would like to run on iOS and Android and wondering the best method approach.

The app will need to make use of external data (MySQL or similar), upload an image from the phone gallery and push notifications.

I know AS3 quite well and wondering if the 3 requirements can all be done using AS3 as I don't know objective-c or am I wasting my time and should learn it?

Comment: yes all 3 can be done with as3

Comment: Great thanks. I have found some commercial native extensions but haven't been able to find one that makes use of the phones gallery images. Time to keep digging.

Comment: I think you may just need to use camera roll though I haven't personally used this yet: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/CameraRoll.html